# Cannot get local media to import into FB 4.6

Tags: image, macos, import, libs, osx-yosemite

Im using Flash Builder 4.6 (to maintain the Design feature since removed - I also have 4.7 - Both registered) I am rather new to this IDE and language, so excuse if my code looks awful, please forgive me, just playing with basics, I cannot for the life of me get a sound file from my HDD to play, I can link HTTP files, just not local, Im guessing Im unsure of the correct formatting. (See below for image of my workspace, including file structure)

```
<i><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="SoundPadX - Home">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                **var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("library://libs/Bullet_Impact_Glass_Window.mp3")
                    var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }**

            protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                {
                    var req:URLRequest;
                    var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                    var s:Sound;
                    req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/4678e9e915ed305c704bb208e1ded2ce.mp3")
                    var so = new Sound(req,context)
                    so.play()
                }
            }

            protected function button3_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                {
                    var req:URLRequest;
                    var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                    var s:Sound;
                    req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/c569fb12aed286d9a36293ff530e10cc.mp3")
                    var so = new Sound(req,context)
                    so.play()
                }
            }

            protected function button4_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/df24dcd8fa4cf7f72f5acd6a314046ad.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }

            protected function button5_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/0a36573fc5f0a3ac6bb1eb077e1c7078.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }

            protected function button6_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/68df86b9f02af0324eb78badaf1db1c7.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }

            protected function button7_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/3c215f5294db2b37f3f15b8b35e149c0.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }

            protected function button8_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/ac21feb2c77136f55e97ebe22fbee7c6.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()

            }

            protected function button9_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/d82d65da7ea01bdb20a3b0f6947bc106.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()

            }

            protected function button10_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/e22ddf144057542f44b3127a414cd8e7.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }

            protected function button11_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/66fd3298f0042f5dbd81c0c163053fe9.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }

            protected function button12_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/865d2d5893fa10e2488d5dc83ed3386a.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }

            protected function button13_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/372ab5d12e4f71b580885ed96dcdd635.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }

            protected function button14_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/1ac11fb2e883dea0098acee177c7bc56.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }

            protected function button15_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/5a93cb85ec7ff1e1d80f6b1379da3a87.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()
            }

            protected function button16_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/85838136dd6ca3f6b311b9d1cf2a7dad.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()

            }

            protected function button17_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var req:URLRequest;
                var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000)
                var s:Sound;
                req = new URLRequest("http://picosong.com/cdn/84b00df302a73f9a4b93a8fda5ba5790.mp3")
                var so = new Sound(req,context)
                so.play()

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
                <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button left="10" top="13" width="73" height="29" label="Thunder 1"
              click="button1_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="10" y="47" width="73" height="27" label="Rain + Wind"
              click="button2_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="10" y="80" width="73" height="26" label="Exploson 1"
              click="button6_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="10" y="110" height="27" label="Explosion 2" fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="10" y="142" height="28" label="Explosion 3" click="button7_clickHandler(event)"
              fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="10" y="178" width="72" height="24" label="Kaboom!"
              click="button8_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="91" y="13" width="69" height="29" label="Thunder 2"
              click="button3_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="91" y="47" width="69" height="27" label="AK47 1" click="button4_clickHandler(event)"
              fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="90" y="82" width="73" height="24" label="AK47 2" click="button5_clickHandler(event)"
              fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="91" y="114" width="72" height="23" label="Helicopter Pass"
              click="button9_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="7"/>
    <s:Button x="90" y="145" width="73" height="25" label="Missile!"
              click="button10_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="91" y="178" width="72" height="24" label="Missile! 2"
              click="button11_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="10" y="210" width="72" height="26" label="Rocket Away!"
              click="button12_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="8"/>
    <s:Button x="91" y="210" width="72" height="26" label="Rockslide"
              click="button13_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="10" y="244" width="73" height="23" label="Freight Train"
              click="button14_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="8.5"/>
    <s:Button x="91" y="244" height="23" label="Water Mud" click="button15_clickHandler(event)"
              fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="91" y="275" height="25" label="Windy Wet" click="button17_clickHandler(event)"
              fontSize="9"/>
    <s:Button x="11" y="275" width="71" height="25" label="Wet Splash"
              click="button16_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="8.5"/>


</s:View>
```

**Screenshot here:**

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCL26.jpg

Comment: You're screenshot is too tiny to be useful, I can't read it at all.

Comment: Just realized I linked thumbnail *facepalm* sorry, one moment!

Comment: My apologies! http://i.imgur.com/31f1n1S.jpg